# Compiling C/C++/Visual C program by Command Line

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, command-line, compilation

I wrote a program in C # - windows-forms
Which receives input from the source code in C / C ++
And I have to compile it and run, and show the user output according to his plan.
The use of Microsoft's codedom compiling classes is not successful, after long Internet surfing, because the above-mentioned functions for C language are not being implemented.
I created a program that opens the command line and sends commands to it, and reads the output back.
Using Visual Studio's built-in command line was not successful because it closed immediately after a few seconds after it was opened and I could not find a solution to this even after a long search on the Internet.

[You can see here my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XtLy.png)

```
And this is the code:

      string vcvars32 = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat";
        string vsdevcmd = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat";
        string WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin";
        string sourceFilePath = @"E:\C_Sources\sample.c";

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            saveToFile(textBox1.Text);//Save the code as c file.
            textBox3.Text = runCmd();
        }

  string runCmd()
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
        info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();

        using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
        {
            if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(vsdevcmd );
                sw.WriteLine("cd " + WorkingDirectory);
                sw.WriteLine(vcvars32);
                sw.WriteLine();
                sw.Write("cl.exe ");

                sw.WriteLine(sourceFilePath);
            }
        }
        using (StreamReader sr = p.StandardOutput)
        {
            if (sr.BaseStream.CanRead)
            {
                toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Parse completed";

                return sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        p.WaitForExit();
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "cannot read output";
        return "";
    }
```

something works, 
But I get an error like this:

fatal error C1034: winsdkver.h: no include path set

although i call the "vcvars32.bat" command, to load all environment variables.
you can see it in the image.

Thank you all for any help!!

Comment: You are creating a stdin stream for `cmd.exe`. The content should be predefined for a specific use case. You can create a .BAT file with all input you send to stdin. You should verify that `cmd.exe` successfully compiles with that environment. If it doesn't, lookup the file winsdkver.h and check what's necessary to get the file. -- When you compiler from DevEnv, the studio adds some path for your that you might miss here.

Comment: I don't know how to create a batch file - do you have a sample or a link ?  can I copy some files to the destination directory ?
 which files and where can i find them ?

Comment: Each `sw.WriteLine` adds a line to the file. Open `notepad.exe` and add everything your StreamWriter would write to `p.StandardInput`. Save the file, choose the file name "foo.bat". Open Windows command prompt in the working directory. Run `foo`.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I add a path?  and where can I find the files I need yo add the path of them?

Answer (score 0):

i'm using WIN32 CreateProcess to achieve same results.

0) read always the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe.aspx

1) winsdkver.h is a file comprised in the Windows Sdk.have you got the WSDK?

2) do you need to pause the cmd execution?
add a line after cl.exe with 'pause' command.

3) add some include dir with /I in the cl.exe parameter string to inlude other headers.

4) you can also create a batch file: 'cl.exe %* > output.txt'
this permits you to pass the arguments to cl.exe and then prints the result in a text file